# Conversion: How much of it should I do?

Tags: conversion, dark-heresy-2e

I want to run an XCOM rpg using the Dark Heresy 2e system. The players take on the role of XCOM operatives completing covert and overt missions against the alien menace. While converting the armory is simple enough, there are a ton of aspects of the Dark Heresy rulebook that are tied to the setting.

I can't convert the whole rulebook but I feel like I should do something with the character creation systems, and probably the talent systems as well. Just how much of the rulebook should be explicitly converted when switching settings this much?

Comment: There's no one way to do this; It depends on what your table wants and what your campaign needs, and we have no way of knowing either of those things. I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based. (Cool concept for a campaign, though.)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I guess that makes sense. I'll leave it up for a bit and then delete it, just in case somebody has done this exact conversion before and pops in.